# Regex for string replace in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to achieve below output using regex but not able to, can someone please correct the regex -

input string :

```
data-placeholder=""[Refer" to "Conditions To Entry Of The Confirmation Order" and "Conditions To Effective Date" sections]"
```

output string :

```
data-placeholder="[Refer to Conditions To Entry Of The Confirmation Order and Conditions To Effective Date sections]"
```

regex tried

```
\s*"\s*([^ "]+)"\s*(?=["])
```

Comment: Take a substring that doesn't include first and last characters, replace the quotes with nothing and then add on the quotes again, no need for regex

Comment: so you want to remove all the inner " quotes.

Comment: @Sayse, the input string provided is just a sample, and double quotes can occur in any part of value, substring will not be helful in this case. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: It still will (according to your reply to avinash), you make a substring going from after the first quote, to before the `lastindexof` a quote

Comment: In this particular situation you can use `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<![\[\]])\"(?![\[\]])", string.Empty)`: this will replace with an empty string all the occurences of quote (") except the ones that stand right before or right after square brackets ([ ]). Though, I would suggest to break the string into two pieces by "=" symbol, and then make a replace inside the second string, excluding the leading and the trailing quote.

Comment: just remove the matched characters http://regex101.com/r/qN1fR9/2

Comment: @Sayse, this sample is part of 1MB markup, trying to clear it so that i can parse into XML.

Comment: @AvinashRaj , thanks for the try. It does clear the attribute but its also removing values of other attributes like <img src="logo.jpg" alt ="">

Comment: @Jack you mean http://regex101.com/r/qN1fR9/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex if you don't want to remove the `"` inside tags.

```
(?<!\])"(?!.*?>|\[)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qN1fR9/4)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if C# supports regex lookahead and lookbehind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
But if it does, this regex should do the trick:

```
((?<!\])\"(?!\[))
```

(matches all " characters that are not preceded by ] or followed by [)

Or use this one:

```
((?<!=)\"(?!$))
```

(all " characters not preceded by = or followed by 'end of string')

Comment: escape first `[` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the try. Square braces are just an example, not mandatory that it will always be there. Also, this is part large HTML file and the replace shouldn't effect other attributes with values which doesn't have nested double quotes.

Comment: @Jack : added a new regex that doesn't depend on the square brackets, but I don't really understand what you mean by 'part large HTML file'